# How to build observables that depend on other observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm not sure if I'll be able to explain this properly:

I am writing a data service in angular4:

```
getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return some_observable.map((rawProjects: RawProject[]) => {
        return rawProjects.map((rawProject: RawProject) => {
            // do some processing
            return new Project(...);
        });
    });
}
```

This works fine. But now, I need to get an ID from `RawProject` and fetch data from another API that returns an observable:

```
getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return some_observable.map((rawProjects: RawProject[]) => {
        return rawProjects.map((rawProject: RawProject) => {
            const vendorID = rawProject.getVendorID();
            getVendorInfo(vendorID) // returns Observable<VendorInfo>
            return new Project(...);
        });
    });
}
```

`getVendorInfo(vendorID)` returns `Observable<VendorInfo>`, and I'm not sure how to return a new `Project` that needs to contain `VendorInfo`. Is it possible to include `VendorInfo` without changing the method signature?

Comment: You mean you want to merge `VendorInfo` into the `Project` details?

Comment: @CozyAzure I need access to `VendorInfo` in order to create and return a `Project`. But since `VendorInfo` is accessible only through an `Observable`, I'm not sure how to _wait_ before return the `Project`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to wait for all the observables to resolve, you will need to use `switchMap` and `forkJoin`. For the "merging" of the properties, you will need to use `Object.assign`:

```js
getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    return some_observable.switchMap((rawProjects: RawProject[]) => {
        let arrayOfProjectsObservables = rawProjects.map((rawProject: RawProject) => {
            const vendorID = rawProject.getVendorID();
            return getVendorInfo(venodorID)  // returns Observable<VendorInfo>
                .map((vendorInfo: VendorInfo) => {
                    //do some processing
                    let project = new Project(rawProject);
                    return Object.assign(project, vendorInfo);
                })
        });

        return Observable.forkJoin(arrayOfProjectsObservables);
    });
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion makes sense, but for some reason, the resulting `Observable` does not emit any events. I've confirmed that all `Observables` in `arrayOfProjectsObservables` do emit values. So, `forkJoin` should be working.

Comment: @user3264740 `forkJoin` requires all the observables to be completed before emitting the event. There could be a chance that one of the observables in array doesnt emmit a value or, error occurs. Use `catch` block to catch any existing errors

Comment: Perfect! I added `take(1)` to the inner Observables so that they can complete. Plus, for the items that were missing the `vendorID`, I just returned `Observable.of(Project)`. Works really well. Thank you!

Comment: Just an after-thought (and this isn't part of my requirements), but if the vendor info changes, my subscriber will not be notified. However, if some of the `RawProject` info changes, I will be informed. So, is there an operator that can work with live inner Observables?

Comment: @user3264740 that is because your forcefully *end* your observable stream by using `take(1)`. Once the stream is ended, even if the source is changing, you wont get notified. A workaround will be to use `combineLatest()` (remove `take(1)` as well)  instead of `forkJoin`. But bear in mind there is a fundamental difference between the two operators.

Comment: `combineLatest()` works like a charm. Thank you very much!